# a loss for binary step function data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, objective-functions, optimization, geometric-deep-learning

I have some data with ground truth that looks like a `binary step  function`, where part of it is 0 and part is one.
An example for the GT can be like `0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0`

or something like this

[image]

I have a hard time to come up with a loss function that can optimize this problem, the simplest option would be something like CrossEntropy or BinaryCrossEntropy, but I am wondering if there is any other loss that I try.

Something that can take into account the property that when the GT is one (`1`) it is continuous `1` and when it is zero it is continuous.

To give a little more information, for example, I will never have a GT that be like this `0 0 1 0 1 0 1`  also I will never have a GT like this  `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0`. In other words, I will have one time ones in a continuous way (it can be at the start or middle or end) but it wont be two discontinuous `1`s.
Is there any loss function that take into account this properties?